# 1;2c OSX mystery: Sometimes 1;2c appears on the next input line

Tags: python, ruby, macos

EDIT: Simplified version (skips [fuzzing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) the console for other issues):

```
pzrq@icebox:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Sep  9 2014, 15:04:36) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 6.0 (clang-600.0.39)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> for b in [89,90]: print chr(b)+chr(27)
... 
Y

>> 1;2c
```

EDIT2: Reproduced in Ruby:

```
Last login: Mon Jun 29 00:43:22 on ttys000
pzrq@icebox:~$ irb
2.1.1 :001 > for b in [89,90]
2.1.1 :002?>   putc b
2.1.1 :003?>   putc 27
2.1.1 :004?>   end
Y=> [89, 90] 
2.1.1 :005 > 1;2c
```

---

Original:

Reproducible (most of the time) enigma I've never seen before:

```
# Setup
$ mkvirtualenv pycrypto_test
$ pip install pycrypto
$ python

# Script 1
>>> from Crypto import Random
>>> for _ in range(10**3): print(Random.get_random_bytes(130))

# On the next input line, get 1;2c printed 0-10 times
# Just OSX Python 2.7.6, does not affect Homebrew Python 3.4.2
# Happens with or without ipython
>>> 1;2c1;2c1;2c
```

Have also seen it change the ipython shell prompt twice from normal square brackets (but can't reproduce reliably) to:

```
In é1ê:
```

I'd guess the first script is printing ASCII control characters under Python2, but in Python3 it's just printing byte strings.

```
# Script 2: Reproduced under (OSX) `brew install python3` v3.4.2 with
>>> for _ in range(10**3):
...   for b in Random.get_random_bytes(130):
...     print(chr(b))

# Lots of output
>>> 1;2c1;2c
```

What ASCII or other control characters might cause this? Or is there another explanation?

Comment: Why not print `b` as well as `char(b)`, won't that answer your question?

Comment: @cdarke Sorry been busy, added simpler case to reproduce it. I'm still stumped why Y-ESC-Z-ESC (if that's the sequence being printed) would also cause an extra `1;2c`